# web browser on ubuntu server ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(237) Gtk: cannot open display

Tags: browser, chromium, gnome, ubuntu-server, w3m

### Question/Problem

I am getting an error message when I am trying to run a web browser from the terminal.

The error message is basically: *...ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(237) Gtk: cannot open display...*

How can I correct this problem/get a browser to work from the terminal?

### More Details

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS on VirtualBox 5.0.8 on a mac.

Network Settings -> Attached to: Bridged Adapter -> Name: en1: Wi-Fi(AirPort)

### What I have tried & results

#### 1)

I used ->

```
w3m google.com
```

It worked(result below).

http://www.screencast.com/users/reed8404/folders/Jing/media/85cdd766-30cf-48a8-b0b1-1d651bc5fd7e

#### 2)

I used ->

```
gnome-open http://askubuntu.com
chromium-browser google.com
x-www-browser http://askubuntu.com
```

They did not work(result below)

http://screencast.com/t/CsKrn4NbYvsA

Comment: You seem to be running without any graphical desktop environment (well, as you said, it's the server install). `w3m` works because it's text based, browsers like chromium need the display server (e.g. the x server) to be running. Since this is in a VM you could either install a complete graphical environment, but this will limit the interoperability with your Mac applications, or use an SSH tunnel with X forwarding to get (probably) a more "native" experience.